# 100% height issue with IE8 doctype declaration

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

Ok I have a simple HTML web page.  Problem is that when I specify a Doctype at the beginning of the page, my stylesheet height:100% does not work.

If I remove the doctype declaration everything works as expected.  So anyone knows why this happens?  What doctype should I use?
I also tried using "Strict" DOCTYPE declaration but still same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the full HTML where height:100% does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//VYOM//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/transitional.dtd">
<html>     
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red; height:100%;">
        testing 123...
    </div>     
</body>
```

If I remove the doctype the DIV occupies 100% of the available height as expected:

```
<html>     
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red; height:100%;">
        testing 123...
    </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: I wish whomever down-voted the accepted answer would at least provide an explanation.