# Why can't I set html min height to 100%?

Tags: html, css

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <div class="sheet" style="width:80%;max-width:1024px;height:400px;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.sheet {
    background-color: red
}
```

What I expected to see was a red rectangle floating in the middle of the screen but what I get is the rectangle being at the top-middle.

It never worked in FF, it worked in chrome before adding the DOCTYPE tag but after that it no longer works in chrome either.

What does work is when I use `height` instead of `min-height` but I don't want to pin down the height value to the size of the screen since I may need it when containers long enough to scroll come into play.

Comment: This addresses the DOCTYPE issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 7):

Set the min-height property to `100vh` (viewport height). Your body's minimal height will then be 100% of the viewport.

Comment: `100vh` refers to `viewport height`, not `vertical height`. `vw` would be `viewport width`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Anyways, it should work like this.

Comment: Finally a working solution to setting a footer at the bottom that still moves down along with content!

Answer (score 4):

Because it's a circular reference.

You can set `min-height: 100%` to `html`. That means it will be at least as tall as the viewport, but can grow taller if the contents (i.e. `body`) are taller.

Since the height of `html` depends on the height of `body`, the height of `body` can't depend on the height of `html`. So if you set `min-height: 100%` to the `body`, it won't work.

However, you can use explicit height:

- Set `height: 100%` to `html`. This will make it cover the viewport, ignoring the height of `body`.
- Set `min-height: 100%` to `body`. This will make it be at least as tall as `html`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sheet {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sheet"></div>
```

Comment: how is that circular reference though? body is inside the html element and html element is presumably inside the viewport, by setting min-height on both I expect both to be at least the height of the viewport

Comment: @user81993: If you set %height to a div inside another div it will be with respect to the parent div. So the inner div's 100% means it's the same height as the parent div, not viewport. Similarly, setting 100% for body means you want to set it to be the same height as html, not viewport.

Comment: @user81993 "*You can set `min-height: 100%` to `html`. That means it will be at least as tall as the viewport, but can grow taller if the contents (i.e. `body`) are taller.*". This implies the height of `html` depends on `body`. And if you set `min-height: 100%` to `body`, the height of `body` will clearly depend on the height of `html`.