# Iframe inside div is not getting 100% height in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am using bootstrap, and I have to display output from one div to another.

One sidebar div has links, and in other main div has to display output (tabular format).

So i have created, `iframe` in main div, but the height of `iframe` is not 100%, however the width is 100% after adding in css.

Can someone please help.

added in bootstrap.min.css

```
<p>
iframe {position:relative; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:0}
</p>
```

Comment: This may help: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: ohh, it worked.. after removing .. <!DOCTYPE html> from top of the script. thanks a lot

Comment: Well, there's another reason for that: [CSS height property, percentage values & DOCTYPE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276)

Comment: does this mean i am using some old property related to iframe, which is not compatible with new browsers?
Also instead of using the iframes, is there any other easy way to do this.

Comment: Can you post a demo on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io? Will be helpful to reproduce the problem you're having and see what you're seeing. Thanks.