# Doctype breaks flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, doctype

When I add the  declaration at the top of my page my flexbox layout will collapse, when I remove the doctype it works as expected. Problem occurs in chrome/firefox/ie.

```css
.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.cell {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jKklf2zeYBjOgTsSQnvr

What it should look like:

[image: grid]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include the doctype and add this to your CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

When using percentage heights, you must specify a height for all parent elements up to and including the root element. Read more here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

When you remove the doctype the browser enters *quirks mode* and resolves an element's percentage height *relative to the viewport* when the parent's height is `auto`. Read more here:

- [CSS height property, percentage values & DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276)

Comment: I actually tried that but I must have missed something, but it works now so thanks :)

Comment: Why the heck does it work this way!?

Comment: @NathanGoings, the explanations are in the links posted in the answer.