# Why declaring HTML5 changes overflow: auto behaviour?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am sizing the web page to make the lower part has responsive height.

When there is some long content included, I want the nearest flex div to add the scrollbar.

All things works fine to me, until the HTML5 declaration is added. A short demo code is made below to demo this. Try un-commenting the declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it changes the behaviour to add the scrollbar to the outermost flex div.

I want to know what happens here, and how I can keep the desired behaviour even after adding the HTML5 declaration.

```html
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>CSS Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initPage() {
        /* responsive sizing */
        window.onresize = function() {
            $('div.main').each(function(index){
                $(this).css('max-height', Math.max(window.visualViewport.height, parseInt($(this).css('min-height')))+'px');
                $(this).css('max-width', Math.max(window.visualViewport.width, parseInt($(this).css('min-width')))+'px');
            });
        };

        $(window).resize();

        $('.lower_left_col')[0].innerHTML = tableOfRows(Array(100).fill(0).map((x,i)=>rowOfCells([i])));
        return;
    }
    function tableOfRows(rows, useClass='') {return '<table class="'+useClass+'"><tbody>'+rows.join('')+'</tbody></table>';}
    function rowOfCells(cells, eid='') {return '<tr eid="'+eid+'"><td>'+cells.join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>';}
  </script>
  <style>
    div {
        display: flex;
        border: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div.flex_row {
        flex-flow: row;
        width: 100%;
    }
    div.flex_col {
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="initPage();">
<div class="main flex_col" tabindex="1">
    <div class="flex_row" style="flex: 1 1 50%; min-height: 400px;">
        Region 1 of 50%, min-height 400px
    </div>
    <div class="lower flex_row" style="flex: 1 1 50%">
        <div class="lower_left flex_col" style="flex: 1 1 50%">
            Region 2 for responsive height
            <div class="lower_left_col" style="background: #cccccc; width: 300px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="lower_right flex_col" style="flex: 1 1 50%">
            Region 3 for responsive height
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510740/doctype-breaks-flexbox-layout

Comment: Yes, works perfectly after adding `    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }` as mentioned in the linked question. Thanks!