# ag-grid is not working when I include <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am new to ag-grid. I started with a basic example, but it did not work properly. I copied the code from ag-grid documentation as it is, then it worked. I wanted to know the mistake that I made in my code. Comparing line by line helped to find the issue. The last line that I removed was `<!DOCTYPE html>` from my code, then it started to work.

What is the problem caused by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Answer (score 1):

This is down to the fact that when using DOCTYPE using standards mode, instead of quirks mode.

You can find a good explanation of this here: [Why does my div height 100% work only when DOCTYPE is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214152/why-does-my-div-height-100-work-only-when-doctype-is-removed/32215263#32215263)

In essence if you want to use DOCTYPE (and you should) then you need to provide a height all the way down to the ag-Grid element.

In practice this means applying a height to the html and body:

`<style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
</style>`

After this if you use a % in the grid definition with DOCTYPE it will render as expected.