# Why does Chrome stretch the 'align-items' instead of aligning them to 'flex-end' as declared?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this layout of comments where each depth of comments (replies) is a bit thinner:

```css
ul { padding:0 } 

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-10 {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
        flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
        max-width: 83.333333%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
        flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
        max-width: 91.666667%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Comments */

.comments-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.comment {
}

.child-comments {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
}

.comment-wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 24px 0;
    padding: 0 0 24px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 100%;#C69F73
}

.comment .avatar {
    margin-right: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.comment .info {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.comment .comment-meta {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.comment .comment-author {
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.comment .comment-author a {
    font-family: 'Simoncini Garamond Italic', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}

.comment .comment-time {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
}

.comment .comment-content p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.comment .comment-content p > a {
    color: rgba(38, 142, 239, 1);
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(38, 142, 239, 1);
    transition: color 0.5s ease, border-bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.comment .comment-content p > a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 68, 181, 1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(38, 142, 239, 0.5);
}

.comment .comment-content .comment-reply-link {
    font-size: 8px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.comment .comment-content .comment-reply-link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FoodBlog - A WordPress Food Blog Theme</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link href="css/comments-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<div id="comments" class="comments-area post-single-comments col-md-12">

 <div class="comments-title section-title">
  <p class="wrap">7 comments </p>  
 </div><!-- .comments-title -->

 <ul class="comments-list col-md-12">
  
   <li class="comment even thread-even depth-1 parent col-md-12" id="comment-3" itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment">
    <div class="comment-wrapper col-md-12">
     <img alt='Author’s gravatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=65&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=130&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-65 photo' height='65' width='65' />    
     <div class="info">
      <div class="comment-meta" role="complementary">
       <h2 class="comment-author">
        <a class="comment-author-link" href="" itemprop="author">Linda Calinda</a>
       </h2>
       <time class="comment-time" datetime="2017-12-29T05:00+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">29th December 2017, <a href="#comment-3" itemprop="url">5:00 am</a>
       </time>
       <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=3"><p class="comment-meta-item">Edit this comment</p>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content" itemprop="text">
             <p>Here we go, another link:<a href="https://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow">https://www.google.com/</a>
             </p>
       
             <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/?replytocom=3#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-3", "3", "respond", "29" )' aria-label='Reply to Linda Calinda'>Reply</a>  
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    
    <ul class="child-comments col-md-12">

   
     <li class="comment odd alt depth-2 child col-md-11" id="comment-7" itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment">
      <div class="comment-wrapper col-md-12">
       <img alt='Author’s gravatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=65&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=130&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-65 photo' height='65' width='65' />    <div class="info">
        <div class="comment-meta" role="complementary">
         <h2 class="comment-author">
          <a class="comment-author-link" href="" itemprop="author">Dana Throws</a>
         </h2>
         <time class="comment-time" datetime="2018-01-01T18:22+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">1st January 2018, <a href="#comment-7" itemprop="url">6:22 pm</a></time>
         <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=7"><p class="comment-meta-item">Edit this comment</p></a>           </div>
        <div class="comment-content" itemprop="text">
               <p>REPLY:: Quite Interesting!</p>
         
               <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/?replytocom=7#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-7", "7", "respond", "29" )' aria-label='Reply to Dana Throws'>Reply</a>     </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

   
     <li class="comment even depth-2 child col-md-11" id="comment-9" itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment">
      <div class="comment-wrapper col-md-12">
       <img alt='Author’s gravatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=65&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=130&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-65 photo' height='65' width='65' />    <div class="info">
        <div class="comment-meta" role="complementary">
         <h2 class="comment-author">
          <a class="comment-author-link" href="" itemprop="author">Lorand Post</a>
         </h2>
         <time class="comment-time" datetime="2018-01-01T18:28+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">1st January 2018, <a href="#comment-9" itemprop="url">6:28 pm</a></time>
         <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=9"><p class="comment-meta-item">Edit this comment</p></a>           </div>
        <div class="comment-content" itemprop="text">
               <p>Him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
         
               <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/?replytocom=9#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-9", "9", "respond", "29" )' aria-label='Reply to Lorand Post'>Reply</a>     </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     
      <ul class="child-comments col-md-12">

     
       <li class="comment odd alt depth-3 child col-md-11" id="comment-10" itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment">
        <div class="comment-wrapper col-md-12">
         <img alt='Author’s gravatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=65&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=130&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-65 photo' height='65' width='65' />    <div class="info">
          <div class="comment-meta" role="complementary">
           <h2 class="comment-author">
            <a class="comment-author-link" href="" itemprop="author">Smithy</a>
           </h2>
           <time class="comment-time" datetime="2018-01-01T18:30+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">1st January 2018, <a href="#comment-10" itemprop="url">6:30 pm</a></time>
           <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=10"><p class="comment-meta-item">Edit this comment</p></a>           </div>
          <div class="comment-content" itemprop="text">
                 <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure? On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee</p>
           
                 <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/?replytocom=10#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-10", "10", "respond", "29" )' aria-label='Reply to Smithy'>Reply</a>     </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>

   
    </ul>

  
   </li>

  
   <li class="comment even thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 parent col-md-12" id="comment-8" itemprop="comment" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment">
    <div class="comment-wrapper col-md-12">
     <img alt='Author’s gravatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=65&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g' srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/13f401b35fbfa320cf306a891828f876?s=130&#038;d=%5Bdefault%20gravatar%20URL%5D&#038;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-65 photo' height='65' width='65' />    
     <div class="info">
      <div class="comment-meta" role="complementary">
       <h2 class="comment-author">
        <a class="comment-author-link" href="" itemprop="author">hey@gmail.com</a>
       </h2>
       <time class="comment-time" datetime="2018-01-01T18:28+00:00" itemprop="datePublished">1st January 2018, <a href="#comment-8" itemprop="url">6:28 pm</a></time>
       <a class="comment-edit-link" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment&#038;c=8"><p class="comment-meta-item">Edit this comment</p></a>           </div>
      <div class="comment-content" itemprop="text">
             <p>Greatness! </p>
       
             <a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/?replytocom=8#respond' onclick='return addComment.moveForm( "comment-8", "8", "respond", "29" )' aria-label='Reply to hey@gmail.com'>Reply</a>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
  
  
 <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
  <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply 
   <small>
    <a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/wordpress/2017/12/19/finding-the-love-of-your-life/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply
    </a>
   </small>
  </h3>
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate>
   <p class="logged-in-as"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/profile.php" aria-label="Logged in as admin. Edit your profile.">Logged in as admin</a>. 
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fwordpress%2F2017%2F12%2F19%2Ffinding-the-love-of-your-life%2F&amp;_wpnonce=f9fd35b4b5">Log out?
    </a>
   </p>
   <p class="comment-form-comment">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label> 
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" aria-required="true" required="required">
    </textarea>
   </p>
   <p class="form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment" /> 
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='29' id='comment_post_ID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
   </p>
   <input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" value="4c1d9851b0" />
   <script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();
   </script>
  </form>
 </div><!-- #respond -->
</div><!-- #comments -->
```

In SO's code container, this looks well and it aligns the items to flex-start (as well as Firefox).

Except Chrome. This is how it looks:

[image]

Here are the **user agent stylesheets** from Chrome:

```
.child-comments {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
comments-custom.css:24
.col-md-12 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
comments-custom.css:3
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
comments-custom.css:1
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
user agent stylesheet
ol ul, ul ol, ul ul, ol ol {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
ul ul, ol ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
user agent stylesheet
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from li#comment-3.comment.even.thread-even.depth-1.parent.col-md-12
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
Inherited from ul.comments-list.col-md-12
user agent stylesheet
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px
    }
```

What could possibly be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

After much dabbling around and googling on what the issue for the re-writes could be, I found the culprit.

Adding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

To your document allows your stylesheets to take priority over everything else as they should and Chrome no longer enters its own styles.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276